# Derived method of base class, is it called through base class instance or derived class instance?

Tags: c#, inheritance

A derived class has access to base class method, so when base class method is called on derived class instance then is it really using derived class instance or is it using base class instance behind the scenes as we know that when derived class is intialized, it intializes its base also.

Consider below example, though it is part of virtual/new but this question came to mind when saw this.

```
 class Car
{
    public void DescribeCar()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Four wheels and an engine.");
        ShowDetails();
    }

    public virtual void ShowDetails()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Standard transportation.");
    }
}

class ConvertibleCar : Car
{
    public new void ShowDetails()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("A roof that opens up.");
    }
}

ConvertibleCar car2 = new ConvertibleCar();
car2.DescribeCar();
```

So when we do this, the base class "ShowDetails()" is called even though the instance is of derived class.

So behind scenes, is it using base class instance. Also when we "override" the ConvertibeCar showdetails i.e override the derived class method then it calls the derived class "showdetails()"

Comment: "So when we do this, the base class "ShowDetails()" is called even though the instance is of derived class." Well yes - you've explicitly said that's what you want to happen by using the `new` modifier in `ShowDetails`. It's not really clear what you're asking. There's only one instance though - it's an instance of the derived class.

Comment: My stupid question answered by a legend, sir you are too embodiment of "vidya dadaati vinayam". What I am confused about is that "new" hides base class implementation, so isn't the derived method should be called as this method is a new version ? did I got "new" wrong ?My whole point behind starting this thread is that when a base class method is called on derived instance... it is able to do so by using a base class instance behind scene ? or does the method actually sit in stack of derived class ?

Comment: in case the instance is of base class "showdetails"  itmakes it believable..because it is being called from inside of a base class method  
..in case base class instance is not doing behind the scene work...then the above question why derived class version is not being called as its newed.
Also when we change new to override in derived class, then how come we are observing polymorphic behavior on derived class instance and at that time how does the compiler know to call which

Comment: No, the instance is an instance of a derived class. The base class method is calling the virtual `ShowDetails` method, so it will find the "most derived" override of that method - but you're not overriding. Basically, you need to read up on what the `new` modifier does.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of overriding methods in sub-classes is that the method of the sub-class would get executed in run-time, even if the compile time type is that of the super-class.

If for some reason you require an instance of the super-class, you should add a copy constructor to your super-class and use it to create such an instance:

```
public class Base {
    ...
    ...
    Base (Base source) {
        // copy the properties
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public void makeStr(Derived d){ 
    Base b = new Base(d);
    ... 
    b.getStr() will call the Base class implementation
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If we inspect the IL generated for Main Program, it looks like it calls using the `Car` instance :

the C# code:

```
class ConvertibleCar : Car
{

}
```

and IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+ConvertibleCar..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // car
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // car
IL_0008:  callvirt    UserQuery+Car.ShowDetails
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

and when we implement the `ShowDetails` in `ConvertibleCar` in the case it is using the dervied class instance:

```
class ConvertibleCar : Car
{
    public new void ShowDetails()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("A roof that opens up.");
    }
}
```

then the IL generated looks like:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+ConvertibleCar..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // car
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // car
IL_0008:  callvirt    UserQuery+ConvertibleCar.ShowDetails
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

and yes it i clear from the IL generator for contructor of `ConvertibleCar` that `Car` contructor is also called :

```
ConvertibleCar..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery+Car..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```